# Applying taxonomy view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have created a view for displaying taxonomies and it works fine it the view mode itself, that is - if I add contextual filters and test it out, in the preview everything shows up nicely, but not in the real world. Is there a way to override the default way posts are displaying with my view?